# how to check true or false two text boxes in single if else statement in c sharp

Tags: textbox

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Meeting;Integrated Security=True");

```
        string query= "select * from Login_Form where Username ='"+textBox1.Text+"' and Email='"+textBox2.Text+"'";

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        sda.Fill(dt);

        if(textBox1.Text & textBox2.Text="1")
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code blocks (done with a 4 space indent) as it makes it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

What does mean textbox is true/false? If you just want check if values are present in textboxes you might use `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` / `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`. Something like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: no i dont want to check values are null or not i just want to check that values entered in textboxes are matching to database or not if values in textboxes and data in database is same.i just want to know how can i check two textboxes data in single if statement

Comment: i had edited the code in code format please check the if statement at last line of code

Comment: @uzair, if you want to test if three variables are equal using one statement, the only way to do it in c# is to compare them by pairs. In your case: `if(textBox1.Text == "1" && textBox2.Text == "1")`. Pay attention that `=` is assignment operator and `&` is 'bitwise and' operator. Use compare operator `==` and logical or `&&` instead.